# application wide function

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel

I want to know Can I define any function application wide ? like say I need a function that gives me dynamic height of label. Where and how can define this function so that I can use it in any numbers of files ?

Also looking for good code of calculating the dynamic height of label based on text. I tried many codes from web sites but that made me confused.

Thanks..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a global function by creating a .h/.m pair of files, but without declaring Objective-C classes in them.

Instead you can utilize C-style functions, like so:

```
//Foo.h
CGFloat GetHeight(UIView *view);

//Foo.m
CGFloat GetHeight(UIView *view) {
    return view.frame.size.height;
}
```

Then you can include the header file in your `pch` file to have it included everywhere.

However I think it's more appropriate in many cases to use Category Methods instead.  A category method "attaches" methods to a class.

```
//UIView+MyAdditions.h
@interface UIView (MyAddittions)
- (CGFloat)height;
@end

//UIView+MyAdditions.m
@implementation UIView (MyAdditions)
- (CGFloat)height {
   return self.frame.size.height;
}
@end
```

Then you can just use it like `[myView height]` as long as the .h file is included at the top (or globally).

Answer (score 1):

You can write a function either in `Appdelegate` or a static method in a custom `NSObject` class which has an argument `NSString`. And based on the `length` of `NSString` you can set the height and return the height from the method which can be used by the class that calls this method.

Comment: The AppDelegate should not be the dumping grounds for global code.  This is a common pitfall amongst newer iPhone developers and leads to a gigantic pile of unrelated code.

Answer (score 1):

Usually I import such classes in the prefix header (this includes categories on objects I use application-wide). All imports in the prefix header are application wide. The prefix header in an iOS projects looks like this by default:

```
appName_Prefix.pch
```

Answer (score 0):

How about making a [category](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html) extending the interface of UILabel by a method returning the height of the label?

Alternatively (however, not that elegant) is to make a singleton class containing the static methods you need.